# How to replace a value in array in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very basic question in numpy arrays:

My array looks something like this:

```
Array = [["id1", "1.0"],["id2", "0.0"]]
```

I want to read the second element of the array and replace with an another character. Its like

```
for i in range(0,len(array)):
    if array[i] == "0.0":
        array[i] = "ClassA"
    else
        array[i] = "ClassB"
```

How to achieve this. I am not able to read "0.0" or "1.0" correctly. 
Please help.

Comment: why the `numpy` tag? these are not `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist - I am sorry if that is the case, the element type is numpy.ndarray. Is this and the numpy arrays are different? And checked for the dtype of the element - it is "str18912".

Comment: ["id1" "1.0"] don't they have comma between them??

Comment: @PrakashPalnati - Thank you for pointing me out the mistake. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two arrays inside an array. The below code should work:

```
array = [["id1", "1.0"],["id2", "0.0"]]

for item in array:
    if item[1] == "0.0":
        item[1] = "ClassA"
    else:
        item[1] = "ClassB"
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `,`s in the definition of your array. your array is the same as this: `[["id11.0"], ["id20.0"]]` (strings just get concatenated). if your arrays are `numpy` arrays then this is the way they are represented (printed). but that does not work as input...

starting from your code you could to this:

```
array = [["id1", "1.0"], ["id2", "0.0"]]

for i, (id_, number) in enumerate(array):
    if number == "0.0":
        array[i] = [id_, "ClassA"]
    else:
        array[i] = [id_, "ClassB"]
```

or, more elegant, use a list-comprehension:

```
array = [[id_, "ClassA"] if number == "0.0" else [id_, "ClassB"]  
         for id_, number in array ]
```

Comment: Protagnoistn - Thank you very much for the response. This also has worked for me.